# Match PEG Pattern surrounded by the same pattern (LPEG)

Tags: regex, lua, peg, lpeg

I'm trying to convert this regex pattern to lpeg: `{ *(?<!-)[, ](?!-) *}`
It's meant to be used as a splitting pattern, turning `2.5 2.6`/`2.5, 2.6` to `2.5` and `2.6`, unless `-`'s are involved. It's part of identifying semver constraints.

I've used the split function from the lpeg [docs](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/%7Eroberto/lpeg/), copied here

```lua
local function split (str, sep)
   sep = l.P(sep)
   local elem = l.C((1 - sep)^0)
   local p = l.Ct(elem * (sep * elem)^0)   -- make a table capture
   return p:match(str)
 end
```

My first stab at it works in the case there's a comma:

```lua
local h, sp = l.P'-', l.P' '
patt = sp^0 * (-h * l.S' ,' - h) * sp^0
split('2.5, 2.6', patt) -- works
split('2.5 2.6', patt) -- fails because the first sp^0 eats everything
```

However, it of course fails when there are only spaces. I cannot figure out how to maintain the original regex pattern's constraints and make it work in both cases. My other efforts have ended in infinite loops. Is there a way to approach capturing one instance of a pattern surrounded by greedy versions of itself, or some clever aspect of lpeg that can solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide some test cases? I don't fully understand why you use lookahead and lookbehind patterns.

Comment: @AlexanderMisel The look ahead/behind is to prevent splits on hyphen constraints. Which I forgot to declare h as D: - I'll add that. The constraints are here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#hyphenated-version-range-
If you want a failing test case, the split should fail if given `2.5 - 2.6`

Answer (score 0):

The default matching method in LPeg is *blind* greedy matching, to simulate the behavior of your given regular expression, we need to construct a grammar with *non-blind* greedy matching,

> S <- E1 S / E2

which will match multiple E1's followed by E2

```lua
local patt = l.P{
  's',
  s  = ' ' * l.V's' + l.V'suffix',
  suffix = -l.B'-' * l.S', ' * -l.P'-'  * l.P' '^0
}
```